# Connect to existing instance of Postgresql from WSL 2

Tags: postgresql, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm running Ubuntu WSL 2 on Windows 10. Before I installed WSL I already had Postgresql installed on my Windows 10. I wanted to connect to the database from WSL but so far it fails.

When running:

```
psql
```

I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

When running:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres
```

I get:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

And WSL clearly doesn't see the database. When running this:

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

It returns:

```
postgresql: unrecognized service
```

I know that one solution is to install the database in WSL but wanted to try to connect to existing instance first.

Comment: Use the local network address as opposed to the loopback address when using psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U postgres

Comment: @RamanSailopal I think I tried that too. I extracted the address using `grep nameserver /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: It should be one of the addresses shown by executing "ip add show"

Comment: Tried that just now. Same issue...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Having the same issue today. Yesterday it was working fine, today I can't connect. Although I don't get the error message on the service start, it just accepts the command.

Comment: I run it in WSL on docker and I removed that from the local - so not really.

Answer (score 11):

You should edit `pg_hba.conf`

1. check wsl subnet
   execute `ipconfig` from cmd. Below is example.

```
Ethernet Adapter vEthernet (WSL)
   IPv4 Address . . . . . . . . . . . .: 172.19.230.81
```

3. edit pg_hba.conf
   `pg_hba.conf` path is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\{postgresqlVersion}\data\pg_hba.conf`. if  you installed Windows Postgresql default install path.
   subnet mask is use value from `ipconfig`

```
host    all     all     172.19.230.0/24 md5
```

4. restart postgresql
   you can restart postgresql from `services.msc`. service name is `postgresql-x64-{postgresqlVersion}`.
5. access from psql

```
psql -h 172.19.230.81 -p 5432 -U postgres
```